# Correct typo in paper title?

Tags: publishers, online-publication, errors-erratum

One of my published papers has a typo in the title. I have found errors of various kinds in my other papers (who hasn't) and never cared to make corrections, but I often refer people to this particular paper and the fact that there is a typo in the title feels somewhat akward to me. Should I ask the publisher to change it? I think they might update their database and the paper webpage on their site, but I doubt they would change the pdf and they will obviously not change the printed version. Hence there would be some discrepancy.

Update: my request was denied.

Comment: You can ask, of course. No issue about that.

Comment: I’ve seen a title that mixed up “deferential” with “differential”, which has still not been fixed. So I take that as evidence that it’s difficukt to fix titles.

Comment: If this happened to me, I'd ask the editor but not expect much help there. In addition, being in mathematics, I'd post a corrected version of the paper on the arXiv, and I'd use the arXiv's comment field to point out that a typo in the title had been corrected.

Comment: @Thomas The technology just isn't there yet.

Comment: Previously I've gotten publishers to fix errors in the online abstract (bad latex code) that they introduced themselves. This time the error is on me so I do not have much bargaining power.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the typo?

Comment: An innocuous extra letter in a long word. Like if you would write 'inifinitity' instead of 'infinity'. It's easy to miss. Also, I changed the title for the last submission, which is why happened.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could ask, although it's likely the publisher will be reluctant to make changes, for the reasons you mentioned: it creates a discrepancy between the different versions of the paper.

I'd honestly not worry too much about it. Yes the typo in such a visible place is embarrassing, but hardly unique. It doesn't threaten the veracity of the paper's results, and readers learn to ignore typos (lots of papers have typos!). If there ever is a "second edition" of the paper then yeah, correct it, but otherwise it's just not worth the effort.